# Is there a way to authenticating without web browser on Facebook API on iPhone(or similar native clients)?

Tags: authentication, facebook, browser, native

Facebook offers an Objective-C library, but it uses web browser session too.

Is there any browser-less way to do authentication?

Comment: Can I ask why? I think that session is quite good. What is your main purpose to not like that session

Comment: Because, it's not under my control. I cannot control those web pages on the Facebook server, so it can be changed at any time. It's all async, so dirty to integrate into my threaded code. It breaks visual consistency. It offers bad user experiences. It's slow to be render than my installed app UI, because all UI must wait for loading of HTML, and it wastes so much memory because of embedded web browser.